# Devise doesn't login when a session already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm having a little problem with Devise. When I try to login with an account, while I'm logged in with a different account, Devise is persisting the session of the first account I logged in with.

This happens when I log with via omniauth first, then try to log in manually with Devise.

here is my `omniauth_controller`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  respond_to :json

  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"]) if request.env["omniauth.auth"].present?
    if @user && @user.persisted?
      sign_in @user
      cookies[:uId] = @user.id
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    end
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

my `user.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can u show ur user model where you have setup devise ?

Comment: I updated with the `user.rb` code

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way devise is storing the data in your session. When you login manually it is storing the user_id versus when you use omniauth it stores other data in the session to know how to authenticate.

You can manually clear it out when the user visits the sign in/out pages:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :clear_devise_session, only: [:new, :destroy]

  private
  def clear_devise_session
    session['devise.facebook_data'] = nil
  end
end
```

Granted it is recommended that a GET request should never manipulate state you may not want to do this on the new action and only the destroy action.

If this is just to test when developing you can run `rake db:sessions:clear`.